# How to get department value in AZURE AD

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to retrieve the department value in Azure Active Directory

[image]

What's the correct calling for department?

**Here is my index.html**

```
  <h1 style="margin-top: 50px;">Welcome {{ user.name }}!</h1>
  <h1 style="margin-top: 50px;">Your Department: {{ user.department }}</h1>
```

**This is my graph_helper.py**

```
graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'

# get accessToken
def get_user(token):
  # Send GET to /me
  user = requests.get(
    '{0}/me'.format(graph_url), 

    headers={  
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)
    },
    params={
      '$select': 'displayName,mail,mailboxSettings,userPrincipalName,department'
    })
  # Return the JSON result
  return user.json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph api:`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}` to get the user information.

In the response of the api, it doesn't exist a field `department` in default. You can append `?$select=department` to the graph api, like:`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}?$select=department`. Then you can get the `department` field in the response of the api.

By the way, if you use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}?$select=department`, it will just response one field `department`. If you also want the field like `name`, you need to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}?$select=displayName,department`

Comment: @EltonTan So what's your problem ? Does the graph api response `department` field ?

Comment: @EltonTan It seems you didn't add `department` in `$select` in your code ?

Comment: @EltonTan Ok, I will test with your code in my side.

Comment: Hi @EltonTan I test with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUvGo.png) code and it works fine.

Comment: Do I need to update any other things other than this? such as auth_helper.py etc?

Comment: I am able to get it @Hury